# The name 'Tasks' does not exists in current context

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version

Following script to play a sound. Sound length 6 seconds which plays repeating for 6 seconds

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() =>
{
    while (isSoundOn)
    {
        player.Play();
        Thread.Sleep(6000);
    }
    return 1;
 });
```

Everything is working fine for .Net Framework 4 but ***I have need to build for .Net Framework 3***.

When I use .Net Framework 3 then it shows following error

**The name 'Tasks' does not exists in current context**

What will be the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

I am adding this because I lost some time searching for this....
All I had to add was the following...

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Answer (score 2):

`Task.Factory` was only introduced in [`.NET Framework 4`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4) - So you'll need to write something like this:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    while (isSoundOn)
    {
        player.Play();
        Thread.Sleep(6000);
    }
});
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

Though it really depends *what* you're actually doing. It's possible you may not even need threads, and simply write:

```
while (isSoundOn)
{
    player.Play();
    Thread.Sleep(6000);
}
```

Comment: I will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Task Parallel Library introduced as part of [`.Net Framework 4`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can use `Thread` instead.

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    while (isSoundOn)
    {
        player.Play();
        Thread.Sleep(6000);
    }    

}).Start();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will do it.